# Not shown bootstrap dropdown menu on slick carousel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, slick.js

I have a problem with using twitter bootstrap drop down menu on slick carousel - on click to drop down menu this not visible. Change `z-index` not give me positive result.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jxdm9t3v/1/)

Comment: Add your code if you want to be helped please

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: On click Dropdown open 2 slide carousel. On click to action dropdown not shown... Change `z-index` and `display` - `position` not help...

Comment: Update Jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jxdm9t3v/2/

Answer (score 1):

Add the desire height to the `.slick-slide`.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/jxdm9t3v/3/)

```
.slick-slide
{
    height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but it changes the pitch of the entire slide and down the lower body ... I will likely give up because of the slider solving problems do not see. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Ivan The plugin has  `adaptiveHeight: true` but it does not work because the dropdown menu has hidden .